# How do return and display multiple values using class templates?

Tags: c++, class, templates, constructor

CANNOT USE VECTORS

I am writing a program for school bug I can't fix this last bug. I try to display the values before and after I ask the user to enter 3 values. They aren't displaying correctly. I have a class template that can be used to create a class to hold 3 member variables. The class called `ThreeValues` accepts 3 items of the same data type (3 ints, 3 doubles, 3 characters, and 3 floats). I know I am writing the function `getAll` wrong in the .h file. I posted the .h file and the `getAll` function is the very last function (at the bottom). This is what I have in the .h file:

```
template <class elemType>
class ThreeValues
{
public:
    ThreeValues(elemType val1, elemType val2, elemType val3); //sets values to 0
    ThreeValues() {};
    void setFirst(elemType a); 
    elemType getFirst() const;
    void setSecond(elemType b);
    elemType getSecond() const;
    void setThird(elemType c);
    elemType getThird() const;
    void getAll(elemType &a, elemType &b, elemType &c); //supposed to return all 3 values but I can't get it to work
    elemType getMin(const elemType a, const elemType b, const elemType c);
    elemType calcSum(elemType a, elemType b, elemType c) const;
    void display(ThreeValues <elemType> &myVals);

private:
    elemType val1;
    elemType val2;
    elemType val3;
};

#endif

template <class elemType>
ThreeValues<elemType>::ThreeValues(elemType val1, elemType val2, elemType val3)
{
    val1 = 0;
    val2 = 0;
    val3 = 0;
}

template <class elemType>
void ThreeValues<elemType>::setFirst(elemType a)
{
    val1 = a;
}

template <class elemType>
elemType ThreeValues<elemType>::getFirst() const
{
    return val1;
}

template <class elemType>
void ThreeValues<elemType>::setSecond(elemType b)
{
    val2 = b;
}

template <class elemType>
elemType ThreeValues<elemType>::getSecond() const
{
    return val2;
}

template <class elemType>
void ThreeValues<elemType>::setThird(elemType c)
{
    val3 = c;
}

template <class elemType>
elemType ThreeValues<elemType>::getThird() const
{
    return val3;
}

template <class elemType>
elemType ThreeValues<elemType>::getMin(const elemType a, const elemType b, const elemType c)
{
    elemType min;

    if (a < b && a < b)
        min = a;
    else if (b < a && b < c)
        min = b;
    else
        min = c;
    return min;
}

template <class elemType>
elemType ThreeValues<elemType>::calcSum(elemType a, elemType b, elemType c) const
{
    elemType sum;

    sum = a + b + c;
    return sum;
}

template <class elemType>
void ThreeValues<elemType>::getAll(elemType &a, elemType &b, elemType &c) 
{
    val1 = a;  //this function won't display the values
    val2 = b;
    val3 = c;
}
```

Now my teacher said to put the `display` function in the main.cpp file. In the main file, I instantiate a `ThreeValues` to hold 3 values of type int, then double, then char, and then float. After I instantiate each I call the display function. In the `display` function I 1) show all initialized values with `getAll` member function. 2) use setter function to set the three values to be user input. 3) show modified values with `getAll` again. 4) call `calcSum` and `getMin`. Everything in my code seems to work fine except for the `getAll` function. I could also be calling it wrong but nothing I have tried works. Here is what I have in `main`:

```
template <class elemType>
void display(ThreeValues <elemType> &myVals);

int main()
{   
    ThreeValues<int> intValue1;
    intValue1.display(intValue1);

    ThreeValues<double> doubleValue2;
    doubleValue2.display(doubleValue2);


    ThreeValues<char> charValue3;
    charValue3.display(charValue3);

    ThreeValues<float> floatValue4;
    floatValue4.display(floatValue4);
    
    return 0;
}

template <class elemType>
void ThreeValues<elemType>::display(ThreeValues<elemType> &myVals)
{
    elemType val1,
        val2,
        val3;

    myVals.getAll(val1, val2, val3);  
    cout << "Initially, the three values are initialized as: " << val1 << " " << val2 << " " << val3 << endl;  
    cout << "Enter 3 " << typeid(val1).name() << ": ";
    cin >> val1 >> val2 >> val3;
    myVals.setFirst(val1);
    myVals.setSecond(val2);
    myVals.setThird(val3);
    cout << "After modification, the three values are: " << val1 << " " << val2 << " " << val3 << endl;
    cout << "The sum is: " << myVals.calcSum(val1, val2, val3) << endl;
    cout << "The minimun value is: " << myVals.getMin(val1, val2, val3) << endl;
    cout << "_________________________________________________________________\n";
//I'm supposed to use getAll to display the values before and after they are modified but since the function is type void I don't know how to call the function so it displays the right values
//it also still displays gibberish instead of the values entered by the user

}
```

This is what the output is:

```
Initially, the three values are initialized as: -858993460 -858993460 -858993460
Enter 3 int: 5 8 1
After modification, the three values are: 5 8 1
The sum is: 14
The minimun value is: 5
_________________________________________________________________
Initially, the three values are initialized as: -9.25596e+61 -9.25596e+61 -9.25596e+61
Enter 3 double: 5.6 8.4 3.4
After modification, the three values are: 5.6 8.4 3.4
The sum is: 17.4
The minimun value is: 5.6
_________________________________________________________________
Initially, the three values are initialized as: ╠ ╠ ╠
Enter 3 char: a b d
After modification, the three values are: a b d
The sum is: '
The minimun value is: a
_________________________________________________________________
Initially, the three values are initialized as: -1.07374e+08 -1.07374e+08 -1.07374e+08
Enter 3 float: 123456 456.789 789.123
After modification, the three values are: 123456 456.789 789.123
The sum is: 124702
The minimun value is: 456.789
_________________________________________________________________
```

I'm sorry I know this is a lot. Please let me know if there is anything I can do to clear this up a bit. I'm not the best at programming.

Comment: How much leeway do you have in this `getAll` method? As defined, it can only ever return a single value. If you are allowed to modify the return type you have options, but currently you have no sane options.

Comment: @user4581301 modifying the return type should be

Comment: `std::tuple<elemType, elemType, elemType> getAll() const;`

Comment: @Eljay I wish i could but we aren't allowed to use std:: or vectors in this class. They just want to make it as hard as possible

Comment: `getAll` just needs to return `void` instead of `elemType`; it already "returns" all values through the reference parameters.

Comment: @cdhowie so then how would I call it from main do it displays the right values?

Comment: @MeaganLynne What you have already should work, if you eliminate the useless `getValues` variable. The function will populate the three variables you pass by reference. So use those variables instead of `getValues`.

Comment: I updated the code above. The ```getAll``` function is now a void type. I'm supposed to use the function to display the values before and after modification but I don't understand how

Comment: `val1 = a;` is setting, not getting. Turn the sucker (and friends) around and you should have it.

Comment: "_we aren't allowed to use std::_" - But you use `cout` from `std::`. Do you have a whitelist over the header files you are allowed to include or is `iostream` the only one?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood you have to return multiple values. So I see couple of solutions:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

template<typename T>
struct ThreeElements
{
    T a,b,c;

    struct return_structure{ T r1, r2, r3; };

    std::tuple<T, T, T> getAll() const
    {
        return {a, b, c};
    }

    return_structure getAll(bool) const
    {
        return { a, b, c };
    }

    void getAll(T* r1, T* r2, T* r3) const
    {
        *r1 = a;
        *r2 = b;
        *r3 = c;
    }

};

template<typename T>
void display_3_numbers(const T& _a, const T& _b, const T& _c)
{
    std::cout << "a = " << _a << std::endl;
    std::cout << "b = " << _b << std::endl;
    std::cout << "c = " << _c << std::endl;
    std::cout << " ### ### ### ### ###" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    ThreeElements<int> te{ 10, 20, 30};

    // #1 use std::tuple (C++17)
    auto [ a1, a2, a3 ] = te.getAll();

    // #2 use struct for return
    const auto ret_struct = te.getAll(true);
    
    // #3 use pointers (or references)
    int b1, b2, b3;
    te.getAll(&b1, &b2, &b3);

    display_3_numbers(a1, a2, a3); // # 1
    display_3_numbers(ret_struct.r1, ret_struct.r2, ret_struct.r3); // # 2
    display_3_numbers(b1, b2, b3); // # 3
}
```

command: `c++ -o main main.cpp -std=c++17 && ./main`

output:

```
a = 10
b = 20
c = 30
 ### ### ### ### ###
a = 10
b = 20
c = 30
 ### ### ### ### ###
a = 10
b = 20
c = 30
 ### ### ### ### ###
```